# SharePoint Products & Technologies Configuration Wizard : System.FormatException

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am configuring the Sharepoint for the first time, using the SharePoint Products & Technologies Configuration Wizard. While configuring, i have selected below options:

1. I am creating a new server farm.
2. Entered the my machine name as database server name, and specified
   the credentials of domain user. This domain user is added to the
   login user on my database server with Windows Authentication.
3. Specified the port number 10100 and selected NTLM authentication
   provider.

After clicking Next i am getting below error:

**An error has occurred while validating the configuration settings. An exception of type System.FormatException was thrown. Additional exception information: **Input string was not in  a correct format***.*

In the event viewer no error has been logged. But few Information level logs are logged stating 'Login failed for user '***'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: **.**.***.**]'. But i can login to database with the same user with Windows Authentication.

Please suggest few things to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across with same issue. I Did rein-stallion of SQL 2008 R2 with SP1 and reinstalled IIS on SharePoint server. Then issue got fixed.